# Apache Proxy returns http 403 occasionally with VAADIN webapp

Tags: apache, proxy, vaadin, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to configure Apache in order to serve as a proxy for my VAADIN (version 7.3.6) application that's deployed on a Tomcat server.

The configuration seemed to work just fine at first. I can login and use the app. However, after a few clicks within the application, VAADIN comes up with a notification:
"UIDL could not be read from server. Check servlets mapping. Error code: 403".

After this message appears and I try to reload the page (Hitting F5 in the browser) I can't access the webapp at all anymore, resulting in a 403 error. When I wait for a few seconds and reload the entire page again (F5), I can access the webapp again. A few clicks after successful login result in the same situation over and over again.

When the error appears the following lines are found in the Apache error log:

1. (When still in the application):
   [error] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http:// 172.16.1.107:8080/UIDL/, referrer: https://www.mydomain.ch/
2. (After hitting F5 and the page is denied completely):
   [error] client denied by server configuration: proxy:http:// 172.16.1.107:8080/

Apache configuration as follows: (The site is supposed to be served as HTTPS only)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.mydomain.ch

  HostnameLookups Off
  UseCanonicalName Off

  ProxyRequests Off

  Redirect /VAADIN/  https://www.mydomain.ch/VAADIN/
  Redirect /UIDL/    https://www.mydomain.ch/UIDL/
  Redirect /         https://www.mydomain.ch/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile ...
  SSLCertificateKeyFile ...

  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLHonorCipherOrder On
  SSLCipherSuite ...
  SetEnv no-gzip

  ServerName www.mydomain.ch
  ProxyRequests Off

  ProxyPass /VAADIN/    http://172.16.1.107:8080/VAADIN/
  ProxyPass /UIDL/  http://172.16.1.107:8080/UIDL/
  ProxyPass /       http://172.16.1.107:8080/

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just forward every request to the backend server? Just a ProxyPass for / should be enough, since it also does forward all "sub url's"

Comment: I actually applied it from a configuration, that reportedly works for someone else. However, I also tried it solely with "/".

Comment: Do you see if the proxy or the tomcat is generating the 403 error ?

Comment: I checked it using tcpdump (do you have a better idea to determine it?).
The dump shows that the proxy is generating the 403, tomcat isn't involved. Any idea on this? Using mod_proxy_ajp didn't help either..
Update: I observed that the 403 only occurs when I perform many clicks in a short period of time on the webapp. It seems the proxy chokes some requests and starts returning 403 errors...

Comment: We use tomcat with mod_proxy_aj a lot and have not observed this behaviour. Perhaps some DOS-preventing settings in the proxy?

Comment: I'm a bit late, but after even more investigation I couldn't find a solution using Apache. I tried it with Nginx and it worked like a charm (more or less) out-of-the-box. Thanks anyways!